# Unable to use IO::Handle or IO::File

Tags: perl, csv, io

I'm trying to use [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle) to create a CSV file with [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV). When compiling the program I get the following error:

```
"IO::Handle version 2 required--this is version 1.28 at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Exporter/Heavy/pm line 120 "
```

My code is not 120 lines long. I have the same problem if I use [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aFile) rather than [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle) (I installed [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle) because I couldn't get [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aFile) to work).

```
$io = new IO::Handle "> Test.csv";
```

is the relevant code. I could not find a version 2 of either [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aFile) or [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle), and installed both using cpan not specifying any version.

Comment: This is where I shamelessly plug [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Array::CSV). Its great for CSV files unless you need newlines in your fields or if you need TONS of speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes from something (mistakenly) doing

```
use IO::Handle (2);
```

or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, that is really obvious now I see it, I forgot the ; after use IO::Handle :)

Comment: I do now get this error instead: usage: new IO::Handle at xxx.pl at line 37 ' (line 37 being the text I quoted above)

Comment: @Lisa, IO::Handle's `new` doesn't take any arguments. You probably mean to be using IO::File.